# Microsoft Edge isPersonal SavePersonalAndPaymentData brake React app

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-edge

I have a simple form, one input and one submit button inside the React app. It works well in every web browsers. Now I started testing in the IE and Edge (`Edge/18.17763`).

When I hit the submit button I got errors in the console:

```
Unable to get property 'isPersonal' of undefined or null reference
Unable to get property 'SavePersonalAndPaymentData' of undefined or null reference
```

They brake the app completely. Any idea of what they are and where they came from?

I do not have anything remotely related in the codebase to `isPersonal` and `SavePersonalAndPaymentData`.

Comment: Are you using some JQuery plugin? If using, please check the related document and make sure they are supportive IE/Edge browser. Besides, as for the ReactJS project, make sure you have added the [required polyfills](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/supported-browsers-features).

Comment: hehe i have the same issue with vue in edge.

Answer (score 11):

It Appears to be some kind of bug related to Edge's Autofill, if you disable autofill does the problem go away? It does for me.

`Edge Menu` > `Settings` > `Passwords & autofill`

When I posted my answer originally there was a [bug report active with MS Edge dev team](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19407264/), but that page is currently a 404. (Perhaps because of the changes to move Edge to the chromium platform?) I cannot find a cached version.

Comment: the link to the bug report turns up empty.  Apart from that, have you found a solution to this issue short of turning the Autofill feature off?  I can't rely on a user doing that to make an application work at an unknown user's end.

Comment: Sadly I haven't found any workaround. But I haven't been looking, I just got that feature turned off in group policy as all the users I had affected were on the same LAN. 

If the issue is caused by a browser feature I don't see that there would be anyway around it. Seems like the best we can hope for is a speedy and smooth transition to the chromium build

Comment: maybe turning it off in html will work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: Figured out my problem - it was a result of adding googleapis.com (for google maps api) script to index.html, but forgot to include the "/" in the ending <script> tag.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was that I had two different jQuery-based functions running in .on() listeners on the same input and it was tripping over itself.

Other browsers didn't care about my accidental sloppiness.  For once, I can say that an MS browser helped me be a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the adding of
`oninput="event.stopPropagation();"` to the input element and 
`onsubmit="event.stopPropagation();"` to the form solves the issue.